# How many $d$-digit numbers with all digits $4$ or $7$ are divisible by $512$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A positive integer $N$ is *nice* if all its decimal digits are $4$ or $7$. For each $d$, how many $d$-digit nice numbers are divisible by $512$?

Comment: Hint: $512 = 2^9$.

Comment: What do you mean "for each $d$"? Looks like a redundant piece of statement. And how exactly does the title represent the actual question???

Comment: @barak: The question is clear enough: if $d$ is a positive integer, how many $d$-digit nice numbers are there?

Comment: Problem G5 of the [PRIMES 2017 problem set](http://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017usa.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A number is divisible by $2^n$ if and only if its last $n$ digits are divisible by $2^n$.

This is because for all natural numbers $a$, $ a =10^nb  +  c$,$0 \leq c \leq 10^n$ is unique, hence $a = 2^n  \times 5^n \times b + c$, so $a\equiv c \mod 2^n$.

Hence, it is enough to check this for all up till $n$ digit numbers,in our case $n=9$.

It is clear for $1,2,3$ digit numbers  that there is no such multiple.

For more digits than that, we must note the following : the last $n$ digits of the number must be divisible by $2^n$. This way, we can construct such a number by adding digits.

$4$ is divisible by $2$.

$44$ is divisible by $4$.

$744$ is divisible by $8$.

$7744$ is divisible by $16$.

$47744$ is divisible by $32$.

$447744$ is divisible by $64$.

$4447744$ is divisible by $128$.

$44447744$ is divisible by $256$.

$444447744$ is divisible by $512$.

All the numbers above are unique with respect to their number of digits. Beyond this, any leading digits can be added to $444447744$ and the number will still be divisible by $512$.

I think from here you can figure out the answer to your question.